# Can't install rmagick in Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tried installing rmagick in Mountain Lion with sudo gem install rmagick and got the following. Any help is appreciated. None of the forum answers worked.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for xcrun... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagickCore... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick++... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries. Check the mkmf.log file for more detailed information.
```

Comment: Have you installed imagemagick first?

Comment: Yes, probably imagemagick is not installed. I suggest using homebrew to install imagemagick on mac.

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me...

As stated on earlier answers:

```
$ brew remove imagemagick
$ brew install imagemagick --disable-openmp --build-from-source
```

I got the magicwand.sh :

```
$ mdfind MagickWand.h -->
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h
```

I then took out the whole path except the actual filename and added C_INCLUDE_PATH= eg:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/include/ImageMagick/wand/
--->
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/include/ImageMagick/
```

I then looked for MagickCore.pc

```
$ mdfind MagickCore.pc
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/lib/pkgconfig/MagickCore.pc
```

The same for this as before:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/lib/pkgconfig/
--->
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/lib/pkgconfig/
```

I then used these two paths with gem install:

```
$ sudo C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/include/ImageMagick/ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/lib/pkgconfig/ gem install rmagick
```

And it finally worked after hours of research. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Definitely helped at least one person :D

Comment: Thank you so much for this!!
I followed the steps above (to remove and reinstall)
but still got the error "Can't install RMagick 2.13.2. Can't find MagickWand.h."  then I followed your steps and was able to get everything going. (I'm using rvm, so I didn't need to sudo)
you saved me a bunch of time and a massive headache, thanks!

Comment: YES! At last after much searching. THIS DID IT

Answer (score 17):

Reinstall imagemagick with Homebrew:

```
brew remove imagemagick
brew install imagemagick --disable-openmp --build-from-source
```

Or you can install using this shell script::

```
https://github.com/maddox/magick-installer
```

Comment: Ended up reinstalling OS X. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: For reinstalling with Homebrew, the second command should be "brew install imagemagick --disable-openmp --build-from-source" I bashed my head against a wall for a while until I realised that. But if you pay attention, you'll notice it's way too fast to be building from source without the "build" part of that flag.

Comment: It's a little late, but you are a life saver

Answer (score 7):

I've been struggling with this Rmagick on Mountain Lion installation issue for a while, and tried MANY different solutions, and this is the one that finally did the trick for me :

Reinstall imagemagick with Homebrew:

```
$ brew remove imagemagick
$ brew install imagemagick --disable-openmp --build-from-source
```

and then

```
$ gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'
```

Thank you to Andrew Nesbitt and Phillipe Gustavo for posting and editing this solution !

Answer (score 1):

The following solved it for me:

```
brew remove imagemagick
brew install imagemagick --disable-openmp --build-from-source

cd /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9/lib
ln -s libMagick++-6.Q16.3.dylib libMagick++.dylib
ln -s libMagickCore-6.Q16.2.dylib libMagickCore.dylib
ln -s libMagickWand-6.Q16.2.dylib libMagickWand.dylib

gem install rmagick  -v '2.12.2'
```

source: http://winstonyw.com/2013/03/21/installing-imagemagick-and-rmagick/